# C# relative path not start from working directory

Tags: c#, filepath

I have a C# program, it will read a file from a relative path `./report/report1.rdlc`, however sometime for a unknown reason it found the file from a completely different place `C:\Windows\system32\report\report1.rdlc` but the file actually is place in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Application1\report\report1.rdlc` and the program is inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\Application1\`. Any reason the relative path not start from working directory?

Comment: Working directory not necessary is the same directory as the directory where your executable binary resides.

Comment: Where is that `C# program` ?

Comment: How did you start your program when it tried to find `report1.rdlc` in `C:\Windows\system32\report\ ` ? Did you start it inside of a `cmd` console while the path inside was `C:\Windows\system32\ ` ?

Comment: I build the program as a exe file and double click in C:\Program Files (x86)\Application1\

Comment: Does the program have a user interface when you double click the .exe file, or is it just running in the background? If so, it could be running as a windows service which would explain the system folder.  If so, you can use Assembly.ExecutingAssembly.CodeBase to find the base folder: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.codebase(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, the program have a user interface, not a background task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does start from the working directory. However, you shouldn't use the working directory, as it can vary if specific IO-Tasks (e.g. sometimes an *Open File* Dialog or (obviously) the `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory` method) are performed. Instead you should use the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` property to get the path where the assembly file is located. You can use this like that:

```
var relativePath = Path.Combine ("report", "report1.rdlc");
var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var absolutePath = Path.Combine (baseDirectory, relativePath);
```

Now you should work with the `absolutePath` to access the file.